# Why does getchar in C accept many characters in a loop but not outside one

Tags: c, stdio, getchar

In the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
}
```

Even if If write many characters in the input and press `enter`, it only prints the first character.

However in the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

When I write multiple characters, it prints all of them.

My question is the following: Why, when I press enter, doesn't it print only the first character in my input as in the first program and how come the condition in while is evaluated before `putchar(c)` is called?

Comment: "Enter" is character of its own, but you do not see it directly, since it created new line. Since line is empty you see that as nothing would be printed.

Comment: @MarekR my question is not about whether enter is a character or not. It's about why doesn't the program print only the first character.

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment about possible undefined behavior, because meanwhile, you have edited the code in such a way that the problem no longer occurs.

Comment: You changed your code in a way that your question doesn't make much sense any more. "how come the condition in while is evaluated before putchar(c) is called?" That is because you now moved the condition before `putchar`. But generally, `EOF` is not the same as pressing `Enter`.

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout)` after every `putchar` and it might behave more in line with what you expect.

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you expect the second program to do exactly?

Comment: @talopl "how come the condition in while is evaluated before putchar(c) is called?" --> `while (c != EOF) {` comes before `putchar(c);`.  Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I meant in the second iteration. Why isn't `putchar` invoked?

Comment: It is. What makes you think, it would not be?

Comment: You should edit your question to include exact (!) input and output. Show it as text, don't describe it.

Comment: @talopl Tip: rather than `putchar(c);`, use `printf("%d <%c>\n", c, c);` to get a better idea of what is read and printed.  Sometimes  it is easy to miss white-space.

Answer (score 4):

The input is line-buffered. When you enter characters and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the buffer contains all the characters you have entered + `'\n'`(new line).

The `getchar` function takes one character from this buffer and returns it. It does not discard the rest of this buffer. Other characters entered will be available for the next `getchar` call.

Example:

1. you enter `123456789`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
2. the buffer contains `123456789\n`
3. first call to `getchar` will return `'1'`
4. second call to `getchar` will return `'2'`

`...`

5. tenth call will return `'\n'`

Your code:

- Your first program reads one character from this buffer, prints it and then terminates.
- your second program is looping taking the characters from this buffer one by one including the new line `'\n'` character too.

Comment: "The input is line-buffered" This is somewhat misleading. Buffering discipline of stdin has nothing to do with the phenomenon. You can call `setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` and still observe the exact same behaviour.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI bear in mind the level of the question

Answer (score 0):

> Even if If write many characters in the input and press enter, it only prints the first character.

Because ... that's what you told it to do.  `getchar` returns a *single* character from the input stream (or `EOF` if end-of-file was signaled); it doesn't bother to look for any following characters.

You wrote your program to read a single character from the input stream, print that character, and then exit.  Any additional characters in the input stream are simply discarded when the program exits.

> When I write multiple characters, it prints all of them.

Again, because that's what you told it to do.  You told your program to read a character and while it's not `EOF`, print it and then read the next character.

Comment: But how come it prints many characters when `getchar` only accepts one? `putchar` should only print one character.

Comment: @talopl: It *does* only print one character at a time -- you're calling it *multiple times*.  You're reading a single character, printing it, reading the *next* character, printing it, then reading the *next* character after that, printing it, *until `getchar` returns `EOF`*.